# javascript - search(regex), get position of the last character of the matched string

Tags: javascript, string, search

In javascript, the `String.search()` returns the position (character index) of the character **at the start of the match when there are multiple characters**. Meaning, for example, if you try to regex search `cde` in `abcdefghij`, it returns `2` (where `c` is at) and not `4` (where `e` is at). How do I do this? I wouldn't just take the position, add by a fixed number, and you'll get the last character (`Position + 2`), that won't work if the match have varying length match.

Answer (score 1):

Use `match` instead. You can use a capture group to add the length of the match.

```js
const [, group, index] = "abcdfghij".match(/(cde?)/)

/* Make sure results are not undefined */

const lastIndex = index + (group.length - 1);
```

Comment: Man, there are a lot of things I didn't see. Didn't know you can start your data like this `const [, group, index]`, what is that? Is it a variable, a type, array, etc.?

Comment: It's array destructing, added in ES6. If you have an array `[1,2,3]`, you can do this: `const [one, , three] = [1,2,3]`.

Comment: so that example changes each element in the array, so `one` turns into `1`, `two` to `2`, and so on.

Comment: Not changing. It's assigning. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 1):

You could always create your own method.

```
function indexLastCharacter(string, search_word) {
    let indexFirstCharacter = string.search(search_word);
    return indexFirstCharacter + search_word.length;
}

console.log(indexLastCharacter("abcdefghij", "cde"))
// -> 5
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the lookbehind also works, like `(?<=y).*$` will return a position after `y`.